# Jboss - java.net.SocketException: Too many open files

Tags: java, jboss

Proper solution for below error pls, increasing ulimit is not a solution for me.

Enviroment - java 7 and Jboss 4.3.2.GA on red hat

```
22:30:08,913 ERROR [JIoEndpoint] Socket accept failed
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:396)
at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:522)
at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:490)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.acceptSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:61)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: What is the scenario causing this?

Comment: Initially when Jboss starts it gets 250 files open then for each hit it takes around 100 to 120 files open and close around 10 to 20 files. In my case I just login to my app and log off for that process it keep open more 100 files. If I do a load testing when 30 users loged in I can see more than 1000 files open. This operation not using any I/O operations.

Comment: At a guess you aren't closing some or all of those 'some 100 files'. Check.

Answer (score 0):

We had experienced the similar error on RHEL 5 under moderate load.

It appeared that default max open files limit is just 1024 which is too low.

Check: `ulimit -n`

Fix for current session: `ulimit -n 102400`

Persistent fix: `echo yourusername        -       nofile          102400 >>/etc/security/limits.conf` and restart session

See also 
https://serverfault.com/questions/44182/is-there-a-way-to-set-ulimit-for-all-root-processes

Comment: Initially missed "increasing ulimit is not a solution for me". But if it's 1024 it's really too low.

Comment: I have done this thing but it not works for me even for 200,000  files it get fail after some operations

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some piece of code leaves sockets open. Make sure that you close `Socket`s when you're done with them.

Comment: More likely to be files. Webapps don't normally open sockets themselves.

Answer (score -1):

You just can't do anything with it until you either increase ulimit or launch more processes. I don't know how you can run multiple instances of your server - check out the manual. Good luck!